# Animate when scrollY is equal to 0.52 - Next.js ( with framer-motion )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, framer-motion

I have this landing page, and there's this part of the page where i want to generate a simple animation with opacity using framer-motion.

The problem, is that those types of animations only happen when you first go to the page, but i want it to happen based on scroll position, how can i make that happen?

This is what i've tried so far

```
 const [scrollY, setScrollY] = useState(0);

  const { scrollYProgress } = useViewportScroll();

  useEffect(() => {
    scrollYProgress.onChange(number => setScrollY(number));
  }, [scrollYProgress, scrollY]);

  // Framer motion - PopUp

  const PopUp = {
    hidden: { opacity: 0 },
    visible: { opacity: 1, transition: { duration: 0.5 } }
  };

  return (
    <DescriptionHero
      variants={Math.round(scrollY * 100) / 100 === 0.52 && PopUp}
      initial="hidden"
      animate="visible"
    >

    </DescriptionHero>
)
```

So basically, I'm trying to see the scrollY progress in scrollY using useState and useViewportScroll from framer motion, and, in the actual component i've made an animation using variants and all that jazz.

The problem, is that, `Math.round(scrollY * 100) / 100` , when the value of that expressin is equal to 0.52, i want the component execute the animation, but it just doesn't work, and i'm having a hard time trying to animate based on scroll position, what can i do ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change `animate` prop, not `variants`

```
  return (
    <DescriptionHero
      variants={PopUp}
      initial="hidden"
      animate={Math.round(scrollY * 100) / 100 === 0.52 ? "visible" : "hidden"}
    >

    </DescriptionHero>
```

Although it is still quite bad way to trigger animation, what whould happen when you scroll is not equal `0.52`? What happens on `0.53`?